Golf Mk1 shuts down, no petrol in the filter
I have a problem with my Golf Mk1 1.3 which shuts down. When I check the petrol filter I find it empty. Then when I pour petrol in the carburetor it starts.
With this problem when I fill the petrol filter with petrol manually so the car will start and I changed the petrol pump with a new one I bought.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please edit the question and include what exactly your question is?
